# How to edit the WordPress footer

Tags: footer

I am very new to website building so I appreciate any help anyone has to offer.

The background of a footer on one of my web pages isn't high enough - see image 1.  I need it to look like the second image.  Does anyone know how I can edit this? I am using Divi builder.
[image: footer 1 - incorrect]

[image: footer 2 - correct]

Comment: Try adding a url to the website and the code you have tried so far - this will help people answering your question :)

Comment: There's no such thing as "the WordPress footer". The footer of your site is determined by your theme, and so the exact methods for modifying it depend entirely on the theme. You should contact the theme author for support.

Answer (score 0):

There is probably some CSS you can add via Additional CSS (in Theme CUstomization) that you could use. Use the Inspector tool of your browser (F12) to see the CSS 'class' element used in the footer. If the class is called 'the_footer', then add this to your Additional CSS:

```
.the_footer {color:white; background-color:black;}
```

Adjust it for what you like. In the Inspector, you can add CSS stuff to that element to try things out. There are googles/bings/ducks on how to use the Inspector.

Some themes have a footer 'widget' that you might be able to change.